# is there an opportunity to optimize the code here?

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to write code for an algorithmic task in PHP, but I don't pass the Time Limit. How could I optimize the code by at least 10%?

> Kuzya again did not have time to pass the essay on linguistic diversity on time. "I probably have some kind of suboptimal keyboard..." thought Kuzya and decided to invent the most optimal keyboard for typing with one finger.
> Kuzya decided that his keyboard would contain
> N rows with keys (different rows may contain different numbers of keys). All keys on the keyboard will be unique.For example, let the text S be equal to ABCD, and the keyboard contains two rows of keys AC and BD. In this case, there will be exactly 3 multi-row transitions when typing:S1=A in S2=B (row 1 in row 2); S2=B in S3=C (row 2 in row 1);S4=A in S5=D (row 1 in row 2).
> Kuzya asks you, as the best Tetris player among friends, to calculate the heterogeneity of the created they used keyboards on the last of Kuzin's essays.
>
> The first line contains a single integer N(1≤N≤2⋅10^5) — the number of keys on the keyboard.
>
> The second line contains N integers ci(0≤ci≤10^9) — the identifiers of the characters on the keys. It is guaranteed that all ci values are different.
>
> The third line contains N integers ri(1≤ri≤10^9). The number ri specifies the number of the row on the keyboard in which the key with the symbol ci is located.
>
> The fourth line contains a single integer K(1≤K≤2⋅10^5) — the number of characters in the essay.
>
> The fifth line contains K integers sj(0≤sj≤10^9) are the identifiers of the essay characters in the order of typing on the keyboard. It is guaranteed that for any sj there exists such an i that sj=ci — any character from the essay is present on the keyboard.
>
> The output is a single integer — the multi-bitness of the keyboard design specified in the input data on the essay S.
> for example:
> INPUT:
>
> ```
> 4
> 1 2 3 4
> 1 2 1 2
> 5
> 1 2 3 1 4
> ```
>
> OUTPUT:
>
> ```
> 3
> ```

Below is my code that I have already tried to optimize:

```
<?php
$N = intval(readline());
$alph = array_map('intval', explode(' ', readline()));
$rows = array_map('intval', explode(' ', readline()));
$K = intval(readline());
$string = array_map('intval', explode(' ', readline()));
$mapper = array_combine($alph, $rows);
$counter = 0;
for ($i = 0, $length = count($string); $i < $length - 1; $i++) {
    if ($mapper[$string[$i]] !== $mapper[$string[$i+1]]) {
        $counter++;
    }
}
echo $counter;
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "multi-bitness"?

Comment: oh sry, the concept of "multi-bitness":

Let the text be a string 
S of length K; Let's call the transition between Si−1 and Si(2≤i≤K) adjacent characters in the text multi-bitness if these characters are on different rows of the keyboard; The multy-bitness is equal to the number of multi-bitness transitions when typing on a given keyboard.

Comment: I've read this several times and I can't figure out what it's supposed to be doing. What is an "abstract character"?

Comment: In general, optimizing puzzles like this usually involves figuring out some relationships in the data that allow you to avoid exhaustive search.

Comment: Add the explanation to the question. And add some sample data with the expected result.

Comment: I added more explanation and sample data with the expected result

Comment: I'm guessing that "best Tetris player" is a hint -- the solution should be related to the shapes of Tetris blocks, or the way they rotate.

Comment: I think this is not a hint, but just a "joke" in the subject of the task, but I will think about your suggestion

Comment: Was there any other hint about how you're supposed to solve this without a brute force loop?

Comment: I suspect you're supposed to find a more optimal data structure, maybe something involving all the pairs of characters. But that seems like it would require too much memory, an array with 10^18 c1c2 pairs as keys.

Comment: No, it wasn't. the barrier is 3 seconds. I have 3.066sec.. but I'm good at using memory. the barrier is 256Mb, on a test that does not pass in time, only 68Mb is used

Comment: But is there some context, some subject matter that you're studying where this was assigned? If you're studying time-space tradeoffs, that would be a clue.

Comment: No, it's just algorithm tasks. No hints

Comment: You can remove all those `array_map('intval'` wrappers, as those identifiers don't serve for any numerical calculations, so they can remain as strings. Secondly, you are accessing `$mapper[$string[$i]]` twice for every `$i` except the first and last. You could use a temporary variable for avoiding that.

Answer (score 0):

You could be making fewer calls to `count()` and reducing how many times you access the array within the loop. For example:

```
<?php
$N = intval(readline());
$alph = array_map('intval', explode(' ', readline()));
$rows = array_map('intval', explode(' ', readline()));
$K = intval(readline());
$string = array_map('intval', explode(' ', readline()));

$mapper = array_combine($alph, $rows);

$counter = 0;
$current_row = $mapper[$string[0]];
$length = count($string);

for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $next_row = $mapper[$string[$i]];
    if ($current_row !== $next_row) {
        $counter++;
        $current_row = $next_row;
    }
}

echo $counter;
?>
```

Main changes:

- Move the `count()` call outside of the loop to avoid   recalculating
  the length repeatedly.
- Use a variable `$current_row` to keep track of the current row, so you only access the array once per iteration.

This should make your code run faster, especially with large inputs.

Comment: Still time limit

Comment: They're only calling `count()` once. It's in the initialization part, not the condition. It's also not significantly more expensive than a variable access, since it's just a field in the array header.

Comment: Array indexing is O(1). Removing a few of these is not going to reduce the time complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: You know... you're right. Come to think of it, the problem seems to be the language you're using for this task. PHP is not the fastest language for algorithmic tasks.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why PHP would be any slower at this than any other language. It's just hash table lookups, they're basically the same in any language.

Comment: Problems like this almost always require coming up with a clever algorithm that's better than O(n).

Answer (score 0):

here's BEST solution i have found:

```
<?php
$N = intval(fgets(STDIN));
$alph = array_map('intval', explode(' ', fgets(STDIN)));
$rows = array_map('intval', explode(' ', fgets(STDIN)));
$K = intval(fgets(STDIN));
$string = array_map('intval', explode(' ', fgets(STDIN)));
$mapper = array_combine($alph, $rows);
$count = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i < $K; $i++) {
    if ($mapper[$string[$i-1]] != $mapper[$string[$i]]) {
        $count += 1;
    }
}
echo $count;
?>
```

it takes 188ms on tests maximum

Comment: seems like fgets is faster than readline, is it the bottleneck? I don't see much difference in algorithm.